# Triggering a Jenkins build on merge from BitBucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I want to kick a build with Jenkins when a given PR is merged to master/develop branches.
Is this possible in BitBucket?
What I try is to create a build with the following trigger "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket", but after I merge my PR nothing happens.

Comment: Im having the same issue, there are options in BB to send a request to Jenkins when a merge is created. But jenkins just ignores this trigger.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible in BitBucket. But you will have to give PR parameters in Jenkins.

Advanced -> Refspec:
`+refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`

Branch Specifier:
`origin/pr/${pullRequestId}/from`

And you would need Stash PullRequest Builder Plugin in Jenkins. There you have to pass your BitBucket credentials.